# Script not looping in python

Tags: python, loops

I've being  making a small escape room project and when you complete an action it's supposed to loop upon completion of certain actions it is supposed to loop but my code won't do that. Can someone help me fix it? This is my code. Link: (https://replit.com/@HoloGrain/Escape-Room-or-Bigger-Project#main.py)

```
    inventory= [] 

HP=100
ImplacedAnemo= False
ImplacedGeo= False
ImplacedElectro= False
print("Type every word beggining with a capital letter")

def Help():
    print("Commands:")
    print("Pick Up (Item))")
    print("Throw (Item) At (Other item)")
    print("Press (Item)")
    print("Hit (Item)")
    print("Open (Place)")
    print("Use (Item), (Command can only be used in battles)")
    print("Use (Item) On (Item or Door(ex. Room 1 Door))")
    print("Inventory", "(Opens inventory)")
    print("Check HP", "(Checks HP)")

def start():
    print("Welcome to HoloGrain's Escape room")
    print("You are locked in Tenshukaku")

def Room1():
    print("Paimon: Where are we")
    print("You: I don't know")
    print("Paimon: We should get out")

def Room1Command():
    ChainsLocked = True
    print("Room 1 Tools: Glass cage (contains sword), Paimon (If you get hungry and     talks), Rock, Door (locked using a sword lock), Chains (Locked using sword lock)")
    print("You're chained to the floor")
    Room1Start = input("What do you want to do?: ")
    if Room1Start == "Pick Up Rock":
        for x in inventory:
            if x == "Rock":
                print("Action: Hey, don't even try")
                Room1Command()
            elif x == "Dull Blade":
                print("Hey, don't even try")
                Room1Command()
            else:
                inventory.append("Rock")
                print("You have picked up a rock")
                Room1Command()
    elif Room1Start == "Throw Rock At Glass Cage":
        for x in inventory:
            if x == "Rock":
                print("Action: You succesfully threw the rock it shatters the cage and you  get the dull blade (6 DMG) and can ")
                inventory.remove('Rock')
                inventory.append("Dull Blade")
            else:
                print("You don't have a Rock to throw")
    elif Room1Start == "Use Dull Blade On Chains":
        for x in inventory:
            if x == "Dull Blade":
                if ChainsLocked == True:
                    ChainLocked = False
                    inventory.append("Chains")
                    print("You have unlocked the chains (Can stop one attack from an enemy and restarts mega-skills cooldown (One-time use)) and taken them")
                else:
                    print("Action: You've done this already")
    elif Room1Start == "Check HP":
        print(HP)
        Room1Command()
    elif Room1Start == "Check Inventory":
        print(inventory)
        Room1Command()
    elif Room1Start == "Use Dull Blade On Door":
        for x in inventory:
            if x == "Dull Blade":
                if ChainLocked == False:
                    print("You've opened the door")
        else:
            print("That doesn't work")
    else:
        print("Action: Undefined action in current state")
        Room1Command()
Help()
start()
Room1()
Room1Command()
```

Comment: Where is the loop that isn't working?

Comment: Everywhere it says Room1Command()

Comment: Please, spend some time reading  ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have already.

Comment: @HoloGrain That's not a loop, that's _recursion_, and it's not guaranteed in your case. If someone inputs `"Throw Rock At Glass Cage"`, there's no path to another `Room1Command()` call for example.

Comment: I doubt that. If you had done so, your question would have just [“Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and that to not the case. You can't expect to everyone go read all your code and help you.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any loop in your code. It just calls all the functions once, and it's over.

If you want the Room1Command to be always running, you can just easily add `Room1Command()` in the last line of Room1Command function. So it would look like this :

```
def Room1Command():
    ChainsLocked = True
    print("Room 1 Tools: Glass cage (contains sword), Paimon (If you get hungry and     talks), Rock, Door (locked using a sword lock), Chains (Locked using sword lock)")
    print("You're chained to the floor")
    Room1Start = input("What do you want to do?: ")
    if Room1Start == "Pick Up Rock":
        for x in inventory:
            if x == "Rock":
                print("Action: Hey, don't even try")
                Room1Command()
            elif x == "Dull Blade":
                print("Hey, don't even try")
                Room1Command()
            else:
                inventory.append("Rock")
                print("You have picked up a rock")
                Room1Command()
    elif Room1Start == "Throw Rock At Glass Cage":
        for x in inventory:
            if x == "Rock":
                print("Action: You succesfully threw the rock it shatters the cage and you  get the dull blade (6 DMG) and can ")
                inventory.remove('Rock')
                inventory.append("Dull Blade")
            else:
                print("You don't have a Rock to throw")
    elif Room1Start == "Use Dull Blade On Chains":
        for x in inventory:
            if x == "Dull Blade":
                if ChainsLocked == True:
                    ChainLocked = False
                    inventory.append("Chains")
                    print("You have unlocked the chains (Can stop one attack from an enemy and restarts mega-skills cooldown (One-time use)) and taken them")
                else:
                    print("Action: You've done this already")
    elif Room1Start == "Check HP":
        print(HP)
        Room1Command()
    elif Room1Start == "Check Inventory":
        print(inventory)
        Room1Command()
    elif Room1Start == "Use Dull Blade On Door":
        for x in inventory:
            if x == "Dull Blade":
                if ChainLocked == False:
                    print("You've opened the door")
        else:
            print("That doesn't work")
    else:
        print("Action: Undefined action in current state")
        Room1Command()
    Room1Command()
```

By doing this, everytime the user enters a command and it gets processed, your code will be waiting for the next input. Which means there would be a loop on your Room1Command function. If I've understood your issue properly, I think this would work.

Also keep in mind that the list called `Inventory` is empty, so you can't iterate over it. You should put some values inside it first.

Answer (score 0):

Fo

```
elif Room1Start == "Throw Rock At Glass
```

You don't have a "Room1Commande() at the end

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing I see is that you're looping through an empty list - so that's not happening.

Perhaps you mean something like this:

```py
def Room1Command():
    ChainsLocked = True
    print(
        "Room 1 Tools: Glass cage (contains sword), Paimon (If you get hungry and   talks), Rock, Door (locked using a sword lock), Chains (Locked using sword lock)"
    )
    print("You're chained to the floor")
    Room1Start = input("What do you want to do?: ")
    if Room1Start == "Pick Up Rock":
        if len(inventory) == 0 or "Rock" not in inventory:
            inventory.append("Rock")
            print("You have picked up a rock")
            Room1Command()
    else:
        do_something_else()
```